# Como ocultar o input (senha) no batch

Tags: batch

Como eu posso ocultar a senha durente a inserção/input no batch quando ele executa?

Porque toda vez que executo ele aparece a senha quando eu digito, para evitar ser vista por alguém.

```
cls
@echo off
title Folder Cofre

if exist "Control Panel.{21ec2020-3aea-1069-a2dd-08002b30309d}" goto unlock
if not exist Cofre goto mdcofre

:confirm
echo Pretende bloquear a sua pasta (s/n)
set/p "cho=>"

if %cho%==s goto lock
if %cho%==s goto lock
if %cho%==n goto end
if %cho%==n goto end

echo Escolha inválida.
goto confirm

:lock
ren cofre "Control Panel.{21ec2020-3aea-1069-a2dd-08002b30309d}"
attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21ec2020-3aea-1069-a2dd-08002b30309d}"

echo Pasta bloqueada
goto end

:unlock
echo Digite a senha para desbloquear a pasta
set/p "pass=>"

if not %pass%==123456 goto fail

attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21ec2020-3aea-1069-a2dd-08002b30309d}"
ren "Control Panel.{21ec2020-3aea-1069-a2dd-08002b30309d}" Cofre

echo Pasta desbloqueada com sucesso
goto end

:fail
echo Senha inválida
goto end

:mdcofre
md Cofre
echo Cofre criado com sucesso
goto end

:end
```

Answer (score 1):

```all-bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

<con: cd /d "%~dp0" & color 0a && mode 60,8
title<nul & title Folder Lock/unLock Script && >nul chcp 65001
set "_crtl_panel=control panel.{21ec2020-3aea-1069-a2dd-08002b30309d}"

Certutil -decode -f "%~f0" "%temp%\2L.bin" >nul 2>&1 && goto:next || goto:fail
:: < -----BEGIN 2L.bin----- G1sxRhtbMEobWzFGG1swSg0K -----END 2L.bin----- > ::

:next
if exist "!_crtl_panel!" (goto=:unlock)else if exist Cofre (
     goto=:confirm) else goto=:mdCofre 
   
:confirm
echo\ & set /p _yn=Pretende Bloquear Sua Pasta [s/n]: 

if /i "!_yn!"=="s" (goto=:lock) else if /i "!_yn!"=="n" (
     endlocal && goto=:EOF)else echo\Escolha inválida.
     
timeout -1 & cls & set "_yn=" & goto=:confirm  

:lock
<con: rename .\Cofre "!_crtl_panel!" && attrib +h +s "!_crtl_panel!"
dir/a:d "!_crtl_panel!" >nul && echo\Pasta Bloqueada && timeout -1 && goto=:EOF

echo\Erro ao Bloquear Pasta...& timeout -1 & endlocal && goto=:EOF

:unlock
echo\ & set /p "=_" < nul > "Digite a Senha Para Desbloquear Pasta "
findstr /A:1E /V "^$" "Digite a Senha Para Desbloquear Pasta " nul >con

del "Digite a Senha Para Desbloquear Pasta " && set /P "_pass="
color 0a & type "%temp%\2l.bin" & >nul 2>&1 del/q /f "%temp%\2l.bin"

for %%i in (reinstall,"listsize=0","listsize=50")do doskey.exe /%%~i

if !_pass! equ 123456 2>nul (
     attrib -h -s ".\!_crtl_panel!"
     rename  ".\!_crtl_panel!" Cofre 
     dir/a:d Cofre >nul && echo\Pasta Desbloqueada Com Sucesso
     goto=:EOF)else Echo\Acesso Negado && goto=:fail

:fail
echo\ & echo\Senha inválida && timeout -1 & goto=:EOF

:mdCofre
echo\ && mkdir Cofre && echo\Cofre Criado Com Sucesso && endlocal && goto:eof
```

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

- Para mascarar uma entrada em um bat, você pode usar a solução de **[@Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini)** neste **[resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24792070/8177207)**, onde um `findstr` é usado comutadamente com um `set /p` já omitindo a inserção do input/senha:

  ```all-bat
  set /p "=_" < nul > "Digite a Senha Para Desbloquear Pasta "
  findstr /A:1E /V "^$" "Digite a Senha Para Desbloquear Pasta " nul >con

  del "Digite a Senha Para Desbloquear Pasta " && set /P "_pass="
  ```
- Para apagar/remover a linha digitada na inserção/entrada de senha, essa solução de **[@LotPings](https://superuser.com/users/639112/lotpings)** nesta **[resposta](https://superuser.com/a/1476789/969781)** // com uma adaptação sugerindo o uso de Base64

  ```all-bat
  Certutil -decode -f "%~f0" "%temp%\2L.bin" >nul 2>&1 && goto:next || goto:fail
  :: < -----BEGIN 2L.bin----- G1sxRhtbMEobWzFGG1swSg0K -----END 2L.bin----- > ::
  ```

---

- **Obs.:** Conteúdo que é decodificado em Base64 nesse bat/cmd resulta no arquivo "`%temp%\2l.bin`":

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

- Para limpar/remover os históricos de comando digitados na(s) linha(s) do `Doskey` buffers/histórico, e assim prevenindo de aparecerem quando pressionado teclas **<kbd>⇧</kbd>**, **<kbd>⇩</kbd>**, **<kbd>F1</kbd>**, **<kbd>F3</kbd>**, **<kbd>F7</kbd>**, **<kbd>F9</kbd>** e etc.., você pode usar uma solução de **[@It Wasn't Me](https://superuser.com/users/969781/it-wasnt-me)** nesta **[resposta](https://superuser.com/a/1525738/969781)**, onde o doskey é reinstalado e um valor de 0 a 50 é reservado, assim apagando o conteúdo previamente armazenado nas memórias transitórias do **[`Doskey`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5661#p34890)**.

  ```all-bat
  for %%i in (reinstall,"listsize=0","listsize=50")do doskey.exe /%%~i
  ```

---

---

Algumas leituras adicionais:

[√] **[Doskey](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html)**

[√] **[Findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

[√] **[Goto :Label](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.htm)**

[√] **[Escape Characters](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)**

[√] **[Ansi Escape Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)**

[√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

[√] **[Base64 Encode or Decode (MacOS/Windows/Linux)](https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2017/04/26/base64-encode-or-decode-on-the-command-line-without-installing-extra-tools-on-linux-windows-or-macos/)**